# save richtextbox text wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to save richtextbox text in C# wpf to a simple .txt file. My code:

```
string RichTextBox1Text = new TextRange(RichTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, RichTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text;

System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog FolderPath = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
FolderPath.ShowDialog();

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(FolderPath.SelectedPath + "\\Log.txt");
sw.Write(RichTextBox1Text);
sw.Close();
```

This does work, however if my richtextbox has the text:
abc
def
ghi

It will be shown as: abc def ghi (on a single line)

How can I get it to be on separate lines like what I have in my richtextbox? Thanks (this is wpf by the way)!

Answer (score 1):

How many characters are there between abc & def? If there is only one character then richtextbox is using just \n or \r for new lines instead of \r\n. Before saving to the text file, you may want to replace all \n or \r with \r\n in the RichTextBox1Text string.